# PL programming using %type

Tags: database, oracle

I am trying to display a specific persons name, title, and salary using %type. It seems like I have declared everything correctly, but it still gives me an error saying no data found. The table is named student.employee.

```
DECLARE
    NAME1 student.employee.NAME%type;
    TITLE1 student.employee.TITLE%type;
    SALARY1 student.employee.SALARY%type;
BEGIN
    --Problem 3
    SELECT NAME, TITLE, SALARY
      INTO NAME1, TITLE1, SALARY1
      FROM student.employee
     WHERE NAME = 'stella'
         ;


    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Problem 3');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (NAME1||' '||TITLE1||' '||SALARY1);
END;
```

Comment: You've checked that the table `student.employee` does contain a record with `stella` in column `NAME`?

Comment: Please keep in mind that the data is case sensitive.

Comment: Ah. Yea I just realized that particular name was capitalized...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use combination of max and nvl to protect your select into form error.

```
DECLARE
    NAME1 student.employee.NAME%type;
    TITLE1 student.employee.TITLE%type;
    SALARY1 student.employee.SALARY%type;
BEGIN
    --Problem 3
    SELECT nvl(max(NAME), 'N\A'), nvl(max(TITLE), 'N\A'), nvl(max(SALARY), 'N\A')
      INTO NAME1, TITLE1, SALARY1
      FROM student.employee
     WHERE NAME = 'stella'
         ;


    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Problem 3');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (NAME1||' '||TITLE1||' '||SALARY1);
END;
```

The other option is :

```
BEGIN
 .. your select into
EXCEPTION 
  .. handling exception
END;
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with the question really; the OP was asking why they were getting no-data-found when they expected data, not how to handle or avoid the exception.